Jupyter Notebook doesn't open
I'm super new into Python and I meet some problems with Jupyter Notebook openning. (normaly I learn with VS Code).
Here is an error:

\[E 2024-11-15 22:50:06.734 ServerApp\] Failed to write server-info to C:\\Users\\48608\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\jpserver-4920.json: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\48608\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in \<module\>
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\48608\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\extension\\application.py", line 623, in launch_instance
serverapp.start()
File "C:\\Users\\48608\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\serverapp.py", line 3119, in start
self.start_app()
File "C:\\Users\\48608\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\serverapp.py", line 3023, in start_app
self.write_browser_open_files()
File "C:\\Users\\48608\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\serverapp.py", line 2890, in write_browser_open_files
self.write_browser_open_file()
File "C:\\Users\\48608\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\jupyter_server\\serverapp.py", line 2913, in write_browser_open_file
with open(self.browser_open_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\48608\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\jpserver-4920-open.html`

Is anyone able to help me with it? (I search through the forum but solution proposed for similar problems were to complex for me right now)

Error message you are seeing indicates that Jupyter Notebook is unable to write to a specific file due to a "Permission Denied" error. This can happen for a few reasons, such as permission settings on your system or potential conflicts with other processes. Make sure you have appropriate permissions to write to the directory C:\Users\48608\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
